# No se muestra un formulario en la template

Tags: django, django-forms

tengo una consulta que haceros, estoy construyendo una aplicación que lee datos de una base de datos, y acabo de tropezarme con un problema que me tiene muy despistado.  Básicamente, viene a ser que la template no muestra el formulario que he creado, os adjunto la info que creo que hace falta:

**forms.py**

```
class BuscarMatCurso(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = MdlCourse
        fields = ('id',)
```

**views.py**

```
def buscar_matriculados_curso(request):
    
    form = BuscarMatCurso()
    
    return render(request,"consultaCurso/busca_Mat_curso.html")
```

**models.py**

```
class MdlCourse(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
...
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Buscar un alumno{%endblock title%}
{% block content %}
<h1>Buscar datos de matricula de un curso</h1>
<div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form method="POST" class="post-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
```

En concreto, tras mirar el código HTML de la template en el navegador, he encontrado que el input correspondiente al campo id en el template, aparece como

```
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="RECQvGvQwS4v8upNfV29ClUkzn1KvuYQ3efWLprY8yc7jRTDsyqQC611SMTl1i11">
```

Con lo que lógicamente no me muestra el input, ¿cuál es la forma de hacer que se input se vea? ¿modificar en forms.py, en la vista?

Recibir un cordial saludo y perdón por las molestias.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en tu view, ya que no estas pasando el form al contexto, tiene que ir así:

```
def buscar_matriculados_curso(request):

    form = BuscarMatCurso()

    return render(request, "consultaCurso/busca_Mat_curso.html", {'form': form})
```

El campo que te renderiza es por la etiqueta: {% csrf_token %}

Comment: Hum, sigue presentando el mismo comportamiento pero ya está clara la cuestión, y es la siguiente:  el campo porque que quiero preguntar es por el id, que muestra el forms.py; pero resulta que es una PK, ¿cómo se que es el responsable? Bueno, he cambiado la definición de fields a `fields = '__all__' `y en el formulario no me aparece el campo ID, visto lo cual, ¿cómo pregunto por él? ¿Cambio a un formulario HTML en la template?

Comment: Lo primero gracias compañero por tu aportación, al fina, he pasado a usar form sin más ysi puedo crear una consulta en base al id que era lo que buscaba, al final:

class BuscarMatCursoID(forms.Form):
        # formulario sin asignar a models, para buscar por id
        identificador = forms.CharField(label="Introduce el id de curso:",max_length=6)

Luego en la view uso identificador para recuperar el valor y buscar por el ID.

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda